# Module not Found while not using require

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, import

Im following a video where is using require to import thing from file to another but im using import and i have problem can anyone please help.

What he did > app.use("/api/v1/users", require(./routes/userRoutes)

I did it like this >
import userRoutes from "./routes/userRoutes.js";

app.use("/api/v1/users", userRoutes);

and still having this error.

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'D:\Do not Delete\React\Expense-Management-System\controller\constroller' imported from D:\Do not Delete\React\Expense-Management-System\routes\userRoutes.j

.....................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `import * as userRoutes from "./routes/userRoutes.js";`